# Java Applet Alert

Tags: java, security, active-directory, applet

We are facing a strange issue in our environment. The users in our environment are trying to access a website which requires Java applet to connect to some website.

When we are trying to open the same from a PC which is not added to our Active Directory domain everything works fine but when we are trying to open the same from domain PC it is asking for permission to connect and gives the below message. The user will have to click allow several times and then it works. We have tried some of the activities but nothing helped.

- Checked all the Domain policies but found nothing related to IE or Java
- Created a separate OU in AD and blocked all the policies from applying
- Compared IE settings and Java settings between the PC which is working fine and PC with error and found all same.

I am not able to understand what is the reason for the issue.

### Error Details:

```
APPLET ALERT
The applet is attempting to connect to Web site
Allow | Disallow | Stop Applet
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's activeDirectory related? Have you tried this on more than two computers? With different browsers/Firewalls etc?

Comment: Yes We have tried it on multiple computers. I am not saying this is Active Directory related but somehow it is happening on the PC's which are added to domain. We have checked all the policies but no avail